# Task.Factory.StartNew - confused about the pool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

Hi I'm getting myself tied up with Task.Factory.StartNew. Just as I think I get the idea of it someone has suggested I write the following code;

```
bool exitLoop = false;                
while (!exitLoop)
{
    exitLoop = true;
    var messages = Queue.GetMessages(20);
    foreach (var message in messages)                    
    {
        exitLoop = false;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        DeliverMessage(message);
                    });
    }
}
```

In theory this is going to drain a queue, 20 messages at a time, attempting to creat a Task for every message in the queue. So if we had a 1000 messages in the queue then in an instant we'd have 25 tasks and it would eat its way through all the msgs. I previously thought I understood this, I thought StartNew would block once it ran out of entries - in the old days that would have been ~ 25. But given this is .net 4.5 which I'm now under the impression that the upper limit for a pool is now pretty high. What puzzles me is that I would have assumed that is going to flood the pool with new tasks and start blocking, i.e. in an instant I now have 1000 tasks running. So if the pool limit is now hardly a limit why am I not seeing 1000 tasks?

[Edit]
ok, so what I'm seeing is that 1000 tasks are queued to run, rather than are running. So how do I determine the number of running/runnable tasks?

Comment: Task.Factory will execute every task in its queue either immediately or when the scheduler finds available threads. Also, you need to pass a cancelation token when using StartNew method to avoid unexpected termination of tasks caused by the GC. I'm not sure how to determine the number of running/runnable task tho.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, the Task pool won't LOCK anything, thats why there is a task scheduler.

Comment: Do you want to know that number of tasks that are currently running or if any tasks are left unfinished?

Comment: Basically I just want to find the optimal way to deliver 1000 msgs given reading a MSG costs C. So by using concurrency I hope to get better than 1000C

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite a while after your post, but I hope this may help someone facing your specific challenge. Your last comment stated that the 'DeliverMessage' method was making HTTP requests.

If you are using the 'WebClient' object (for example) to make your requests, it will be bound by the [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) property. This means it will create at most two (by default) concurrent connections to the host. If you created 1,000 parallel tasks, all 1,000 of those would have to be serviced by those two connections.

You'll have to play around with different values for this setting to find the right balance between throughput in your application and load on the web server.